# No. of ways of arranging $n$ objects in $r$ sets of $k$ identical boxes

Tags: combinatorics

What are the no. of ways of arranging $n$ objects in $r$ sets of $k$ identical boxes. Arrangement of objects within boxes matters and each set is non identical. Boxes can be empty.

I know the solution of how to arrange the objects into boxes when all are distinct, but I was not able to crack this one.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: With $n=4, r=2, k=2$, and using colors to denote the difference in types of boxes, you are saying that $\color{red}{(1,2),(~)},\color{blue}{(3),(4)}$ is considered the same arrangement as $\color{red}{(~),(1,2)},\color{blue}{(4),(3)}$ but is a different arrangement than $\color{red}{(2,1),(~)},\color{blue}{(3),(4)}$ since the order within one of the boxes is different?

Comment: yes your third arrangement is different from both first and second while both first and second are same

Comment: @ViktorGlombik incorrect.  That would be if order within the boxes is irrelevant and there was only one of each box in each set.

Comment: "each set is non identical" = each set is distinguishable (labeled) ?

Comment: and , objects are distinguished or not ?

Comment: @GCab I assume you can extract the answers from the comment of JMoravitz and the response to it.

Comment: @GCab objects are distinct and sets are distinguishable

Answer (score 0):

Look at this post:

[Different ways of Arranging balls in boxes](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/802724/632943)

Comment: I know these methods but how i can apply these to my problem ?

Comment: @njjw You first calculate the number of ways of distributing $n$ objects in $r$ sets and then you multiply it for the number of ways of distributing the objects of a set between the boxes.